# Calendar datasheet view from today and ongoing events

Tags: calendar

My org adds people's vacation dates in the SharePoint 2019 calendar as events. Usually it is 1-2 weeks off at a time and it is recorded as a single multiday event.
I want a datasheet view that shows future dates as well as ongoing events like the vacation blocks. I can only think of filter Start Date >= [Today] which obviously doesn't work if someone is in the middle of their vacation. What other filter should I try?

Answer (score 0):

Well just use `End Date >= [Today]`, it will show all future events and running events, where end date is still not past today.